# Build with Travis-ci and push some files/folder to another repository

Tags: git, github, travis-ci

If anyone can take a look at this and maybe point me in the right direction. It's been 2 days and I can't find a solution. There is a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18027115/comitting-via-travis-ci-failing), and I may be missing something.
You can see the travis-ci build log [here](https://travis-ci.org/JamesDullaghan/foundation/builds/13650473)

The error message is:

```
remote: Anonymous access to JamesDullaghan/bower-foundation-css.git denied.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/JamesDullaghan/bower-foundation-css.git/'
```

.travis.yml file

```
language: node_js
node_js:
- '0.10'
env:
  global:
  - secure: some-long-string-of-characters-numbers
branches:
  only:
  - somebranch
before_script:
  - echo -e "Host github.com\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n" >> ~/.ssh/config
  - git config --global user.email "myemail@email.com"
  - git config --global user.name "myname"
  - git config credential.helper "store --file=~/.git/credentials"
  - echo "https://${GH_TOKEN}:@github.com" > ~/.git/credentials
script:
- npm install grunt
- npm install grunt-cli
- grunt compile
after_success:
- git clone https://github.com/myname/repo2.git
- cp -r dist/assets/* repo2/
- cd repo2
- git add .
- git commit -m "build to repo2"
- git push -fq origin master
- echo -e "Done with magic\n"
```

I have run `travis encrypt GH_TOKEN="mytoken" --add` and I've tried creating a new token in github twice to see if I was doing that incorrectly.

Any help at this point is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935539/authenticate-with-github-using-token?rq=1), although it's not using the `.git/credentials/` file.

In summary, we can't control the way Travis-ci clones the repository. This means the remote isn't setup with authentication credentials, so we remove the remote, and add the remote with credentials:

```
cd clonedrepofolder
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin https://username:${GH_TOKEN}@github.com/username/repo.git
```