# How do I generate the GitHub OAuth token for organization accounts?

Tags: git, github, github-api, github-pages

I have created an organization on GitHub. My organization has some repos. These repos have API documentation that I would like to re-build and publish to `gh-pages` branch via Travis-CI.  In order to give Travis-CI access to my organization's repos I need to generate an OAuth token, encrypt it, and then add then include the encypted token in the `.travis.yml` file as follows...

```
env:
  global:
  - secure: "lots-of-seemingly-random-characters"
```

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18027115/committing-via-travis-ci-failing) explains the process and provides the details on how to do this for user accounts. How do I generate the required OAuth token for organization accounts?

Comment: Seems like [on `gitlab.com` this isn't possible](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/37778) either.

Comment: For access to a specific org-level repository, a [deploy-key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72414537/6813271) may be a viable alternative to a token.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

That's not possible currently, you can only create tokens for user accounts since user accounts have permissions associated with them (organizations don't). So, you'd need to create a token with an account which has access to the repository in question and give that to Travis. You can also create a machine account for that purpose.

Comment: Do you have any plan to support this?

Comment: So if the user associated with these accounts leaves the organization we would have to replace all of the tokens in our travis files?

Is this intentionally not supported, or just not yet supported?

Comment: What is a "machine account", I can't seem to find documentation on this.

Comment: Nevermind, I see its just an account that is created specifically for use by the org for automation. Nothing fancy.

Comment: About "machine account": https://developer.github.com/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#machine-users

Comment: Problem is that machine account takes up a seat in the organization.

Comment: hi, is there any update on the org token?

Comment: https://micahjon.com/2021/repo-scoped-access-token-for-github-org/

Comment: As of Nov 2022, the solution is to use GitHub Apps as per [the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.4/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token#about-personal-access-tokens):

> Personal access tokens are intended to access GitHub resources on behalf of yourself. To access resources on behalf of an organization, or for long-lived integrations, you should use a GitHub App..