# How to login into a Travis Enterprise using Travis CLI?

Tags: travis-ci, travis-ci-cli

I'm trying to login to an own hosted Travis Enterprise, but usual `travis login` and `travis login --pro` are trying to login to usual Travis SAAS environment

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Given that your Travis is hosted at `travis.fewlaps.com`, run

```bash
travis login -I -t your-travis-token -e https://travis.fewlaps.com/api --github-token=personal-access-token-from-githubenterprise
```

To use your own Travis, instead of the common one, for future `travis` commands

```bash
travis endpoint --set-default -e https://travis.fewlaps.com/api
```

With this, one can drop the `-e https://travis.fewlaps.com/api` for the above login command.

Remember that Travis will need that your GitHub Enterpise has the needed permissons. Right now, we're giving to that token these permissions:

- repo *(all of them)*
- admin:repo_hook
- user

Comment: Thanks. This made my Friday!

Comment: Nice! I wrote it at StackOverflow to remember it to me of the future... and also to you! :·D

Comment: @RocBoronat Does this still work for you? I tried your instructions, and while I could login, it did not save my credentials (https://github.com/travis-ci/travis.rb/issues/588)

Comment: @arewm sorry, but now I don't use Travis anymore, so I can't try it again.

Comment: @RocBoronat No problem. I had someone else from my company try logging in. There is just something bizarre with my computer apparently...

Comment: @arewm haha, well, thanks for sharing that the answer is up to date! :·D

Comment: Facing to the "SSL error: could not verify peer", though "-I" is specified in command which means "do not verify SSL certificate of API endpoint"...

Comment: Note: if you use the `travis endpoint ...` first, then the login command shortens to `travis login  --github-token ....`

Answer (score 12):

For those still struggling with this, the following helped me:

`travis login --pro -X --github-token ${github-token}`

Make sure you set the github token for your [personal account with access to the private repos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31160721/4028718) as detailed [here](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line), and create the token with the following permissions:

For private projects:

- user:email (read-only)
- read:org (read-only)
- repo

for open source projects:

- user:email (read-only)
- read:org (read-only)
- repo_deployment
- repo:status
- write:repo_hook

Answer (score 3):

I have been struggling with this for several months and finally figured it out (accidentally). You can use the `-X` option to log into enterprise accounts. This might have always been present, but I was not aware of it.

```
travis login -X --github-token ${my-github-enterprise-token}
```

Then enter the enterprise domain when prompted and use it as the default endpoint.

Comment: For enterprise Travis with enterprise GitHub, I had to specify the Travis domain: `travis login -e "https://travis.example.com/api" -X --github-token ...`