# Is there a way to authenticate to github from a script without using a personal access token?

Tags: git, github, build-automation

I am trying to automate the deployment of our android and ios apps and there is one step that I can't seem to automate.

I've created a bash script as well as a dart script that work together to do most everything else. the deployment aspect is managed by fastlane and everything else seems to work fine.

After automatically updating our changelog and iterating to the next build number I need to be able to commit the changes with a default "preparing for app deployment" message.
However all I can seem to do is authenticate with my personal access token or ssh token, which I believe tie it to my personal account.

I've looked into github cli and I can do something like this but it still uses a personal account:

`gh auth login --with-token < (insert token here)`

Is there way to do this with something like a service account that is only allowed certain permissions?

I want to future proof this so that it isn't tied to someone's account that could leave the organization in the future.

Comment: Committing and pushing are two unrelated processes. Whatever user commits is not necessarily who will end up pushing (and whoever pushes is not tracked as informarion in the revisions in git). What is the issue?

Comment: Any authentication is going to be tied to an actual GitHub account. In our organization, we have created a "bot" account for automation purposes. We use the token for the bot account when interacting with github from workflows, etc.

Comment: Create an account that belongs to your organisation, not a person. Depending on your policies you could either let IT have access to that github account or your CTO or your CEO or the business owner etc.

Comment: @eftshift0 in this particular case it would be a commit directly to develop(we use this as our master branch) to commit the new build number and set new changes to the deployed section of our changelog. these would be the only commits that need to be automated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [deploy key with write access](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/managing-deploy-keys#deploy-keys=).

[image: https://docs.github.com/assets/cb-390813/images/deploy-key.png]

That way, it is tied to the repository, not a personal account.