# In Travis Public Repository how to add a Secure variable that works on Pull requests too

Tags: security, authentication, travis-ci

I have Travis-ci on a public repository. After finishing the execution it generates a image that I want to upload to cloudinary.com, but it could be any other service.

The problem is that to do it, I need to add in .travis.yml the auth token. But I don't want to expose it publicly, and for that travis offers a way to secure Env variables: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Secure-Variables. However they do not work on PULL requests:

> Secure Env variables are not available on pull requests from forks due
>   to security risk of exposing such information to unknown code.
>   Encryption and decryption keys are tied to the repository. If you fork
>   a project and add it to Travis CI, it will have different keys to the
>   original.

Anyone has any idea about how could I add an hidden value that is available for PUSH and PULL REQUESTS?

Comment: So simply merging the pull requests doesn't do the trick for you?

Comment: No, because I want to run the automated tests over pull requests that send unknown people. If they pass the tests, then I will merge these pulls. Travis will do comments automatically on these pull requests with the results of the tests.

I can't use the reply in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18027115/committing-via-travis-ci-failing due to the same thing. It affects pull requests

Comment: Did you figure out on how to use travis secure variables available for pull requests?

Comment: Not yet @SaurabhShah

Comment: If you post a link to your repository, I can have a look at it, and see how your `.travis.yml` differs from one which works, such as the one in our project: https://github.com/eclipse/scanning/blob/master/.travis.yml

Answer (score 1):

As you already wrote in your question: according to the official Travis CI documentation https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables you won't have access to these variables from untrusted builds such as pull requests. This makes sense, since someone could submit a pull request to your repository containing malicious code which then exposes your secret value.

Bottom line: if you want to make secret values available to pull requests, you have to assume they're not secret anymore - therefore you could also just hard code the unencrypted value to your `.travis.yml` and use it from there. Which doesn't seem like a good idea. ;-)

Possible solution in your case: you could just use an image hoster which provides anonymous uploading? You wouldn't need an auth key, so your pull requests would be able to upload, too.