# How to automatically add issues to GitHub repo from Sonarcloud issues

Tags: sonarqube, sonarcloud

After every Sonarcloud analysis of my GitHub repo, I get informed of issues and bugs on Sonarcloud's project page. Is there a way to automate the process to get those issues published to GitHub issues of my repository?

---

Edit:
Also see this question: [How do I get Sonarcloud to run on pull requests from forks with Travis, Maven & github](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45612758) and this answer to it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45776416.

Comment: did you find an answer? I found only this: https://stef-heyenrath.medium.com/how-to-fix-sonarcloud-issue-in-a-github-pr-when-using-appveyor-integration-8909b49406b4

Comment: @JegorsČemisovs no, unfortunately I wasn't able to find anything related to my problem, so I just gave up.