# How to auto-upgrade a gem in travis?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, travis-ci, continuous-deployment, rails-engines

I help to maintain [an open source project](https://github.com/samvera/hyrax), Hyrax, which is a rails engine. In order to do QA on new development, we maintain [an application that is specifically for QA](https://github.com/curationexperts/nurax), Nurax, which should always be updated with the latest master of the rails engine. I have specified the master branch of Hyrax in the `Gemfile` for Nurax, and if I run `bundle update hyrax` it will indeed get the latest master version and update the `Gemfile.lock` accordingly. I can also get Nurax to deploy automatically via Travis. However, that auto-deploy does not automatically update to the latest master of Hyrax before deploying, which is what I really want to happen.

What is the best way to set this up? Should I have travis run a `bundle update hyrax` and commit that change to Nurax master as part of its build? I've found a few topics about committing from a travis build (e.g., [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18027115/committing-via-travis-ci-failing)). Would it be better to make a new Nurax branch for each PR and deploy that branch? Is there an established pattern for this that I could be following?

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you're on the right track with: *...have travis run a `bundle update hyrax` and commit that change to Nurax master as part of its build...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this with a cron job. I checked out a local copy of the code on the server in question, in the home directory of my `ubuntu` user. I then added the `ubuntu` user's ssh key to my own github account, and to the account used for capistrano deploy. Then, I set this up to run daily:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby

# Get the latest nurax master
# Make a branch with today's date and update hyrax
# Push and deploy that branch

today = Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%e-%H-%M')
`cd /home/ubuntu/nurax; git checkout master; git pull; git checkout -b "#{today}"`
`cd /home/ubuntu/nurax; bundle update hyrax`
`cd /home/ubuntu/nurax; git commit -a -m 'Daily update for "#{today}"'; git push --set-upstream origin #{today}`
`cd /home/ubuntu/nurax; BRANCH_NAME="#{today}" cap nurax-dev deploy`
`cd /home/ubuntu/nurax; git checkout master; git branch -d "#{today}"; git push origin --delete "#{today}"`
```